# How to do 'fossil' commands on relative directory?

Tags: version-control, fossil

I want to keep my linux config in fossil scm system.

Here is what I did at initial stage.

```
$ cd /
$ fossil new b.fsl
$ fossil open b.fsl
$ fossil add etc/group
$ fossil add boot/grub/menu.lst
$ fossil ci -m 'init commit'
```

I want do do things like (operate like hg/git).

```
$ cd etc
$ fossil status group
$ fossil add motd
```

It will show error message:

```
fossil: current directory is not within an open checkout
```

So, my temp dirty solution is

```
$ cd /
$ fossil status etc/group
$ fossil add etc/motd
$ fossil add /etc/motd # this line will cause problem
```

For my git/hg experiences, it should work.

```
$ cd /
$ hg init
$ hg add etc/group boot/grub/menu.lst
$ hg ci -m 'init commit'
$ cd etc
$ hg status group  # it works
$ hg add motd # it works too
```

Answer (score 2):

Before the command

```
$ fossil new b.fsl
```

Type the command

```
$ cd etc
```

If you want the fossil repo stored in another folder, change the commands

```
$ fossil new b.fsl
$ fossil open b.fsl
```

to

```
$ fossil new path_to_repo/b.fsl
$ fossil open path_to_repo/b.fsl
```

Comment: I want to keep etc sub-directory name.

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  I am not suggesting you change the name of the /etc directory!

Comment: I want keep the information /etc/... /boot/..., in hg/git, it will check ancestry directory to get relative directory information.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to clarify what the problem is, and why the solution I have suggested does not solve it.  Your comments are too brief for me to understand.

Comment: I'm wonder should I force to write full file name if I have many subdirectories, I don't think it is a smart/correct method.

Comment: I guess this problem may caused by a not solved fossil's bug(even on 2013/01/10 c7133bd79d)

Answer (score 2):

All mentioned commands "add" and "status" and all fossil commands related to the checkout must be executed when the current directory is set somewhere inside the directory tree of the checkout.

You can't specify the checkout directory yourself as a command line option.

It seems there is a bug (or intentionally introduced feature) in fossil that prevents it searching for the open checkout file (".fslchkout" or "*FOSSIL*") up to the root directory. That is why in this case you must be in the root directory when you execute commands on this checkout.

Of course all executions of fossil in this case must be with root privileges. Otherwise, even in the root directory you will get "not within checkout" error.

Comment: I've specified add stat under opened directory.  These command works fine under sub-directory but root.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. It seems it is a bug in fossil. It simply does not search properly for the file ".fslchkout" which indicates the open checkout, when this file is located in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is covered in great detail in the `User Guide`, which I recommend wholeheartedly.

http://www.fossil-scm.org/schimpf-book/home

In particular, see version 2.0 of the `fossilbook.pdf`, in section 2, entitled "Single Users", the section starting with:

> I have a directory called FOSSIL in which I keep all my repositories, Fossil doesn’t care but it helps me to keep them all in one place so I can back them up.

The first command there shows how to call relative directories:

```
$ fossil new ../FOSSIL/FossilBook.fossil
```

Comment: Could you point out which section have the same situation? I've ever read the old version of this book.

Comment: @DanielYCLin, unless I misread the question, section 2 has examples (see my edit above).

Comment: The key point of this question is '/'. Root directory problem.

Comment: @DanielYCLin, Ok, perhaps clarify this in your question, so others may benefit from it and the answer?